# Creating a Generic Class that Extends SAXParser's Default Handler

Tags: java, generics, saxparser, type-parameter

I have a few tables that I have `SELECT *`'d into XML files. Lets call them table A, B and C which map to java classes A, B, and C. Instead of making a separate AXMLDao, BXMLDao, and CXMLDao, I wish to have one generic class.

A, B, and C have member variable that map to their respective A, B, and C tables. I have `public static Map<String, Method> getSetMethodMap()` in each A,B,C class that returns a mapping of the database field name to the mutator method in the respective class using the reflection API.

I have made a current implementation but it fails on two counts: 1) its full of warnings because I'm not doing it correctly, and 2) I'm not sure how I would be able to access the `getSetMethodMap()` through a type parameter.;

If I create an interface called ReflectionType with a non-static method of `public Map<String,Method> getMethodMap();` and change the following implementation to `<T extends ReflectionType>` then I can set the methodMap.. but this feels wrong.

This is my current implementation.

```
public class GenericXMLDao<T> extends DefaultHandler {
    List<T> rows;
    String xmlFileName;
    Map<String, Method> methodMap; // This is for Reflection API
    T tempRow;

    String tempValue;

    public static Map<Class, String> getXMLFileMap() {
        Map<Class, String> map = new HashMap<Class, String>();
        map.put("A.class", "C:\\A.xml");
        ....
        return map;
    }

    public String fetchXMLFileName(Class c) {
        Map<Class,String> map = GenericXMLDao.getXMLFileMap();
        // Try Catch Throw exception if Class is not in map, but essentially:
        return map.get(c);
    }

    public List<T> getAllRows(Class c) {
        rows = new ArrayList<T>();
        xmlFileName = fetchXMLFileName(c);
        parseDocument();
        return rows;
    }

    private void parseDocument() {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(xmlFileName, this);
        // catch ....
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATA_RECORD")) {
            try {
                tempRow = (T) tempRow.getClass().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {
    if (element.equals("DATA_RECORD")) {
        rows.add(tempRow);
    }

    for (Entry<String,Method> entry : methodMap.entrySet()) {
        // Try ... catch reflection api
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey))) {
            entry.getValue().invoke(tempRow, tempValue);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
    tempValue = new String(ac, i, j);
}
```

I'm clearly not grasping the generic/type parametrization appropriately.

How can this be cleaned up?

Comment: Could you please post the warnings (lines and messages)?

Answer (score 0):

As for me,

```
<T extends ReflectionType>
```

is the way to go if you need to call certain methods of class `T` (as `getSetMethodMap` in this case).